# If the input is empty, how do I display something else with PHP?

Tags: php, wordpress

My WordPress options panel has a section where the user can paste their logo's URL to show up in the header. If the input is blank, I want the Blog's title to show up instead on my header. The ID of the input is "nl_logo", so I added an if statement in my header.

```
<?php if ("nl_logo") { ?>
    <img src="<?php echo get_option('nl_logo'); ?>">
<?php } else { ?>
    <h1><a href="'get_site_url()' ?>"><?php bloginfo('name'); ?></a></h1>
<?php } ?>
```

The first part of the if statement works. However, anything below else doesn't work when I have no URL saved in my input. So, if the input is empty, how do I display something else with PHP? Or is there a different and better way to do this? For example, creating a function and calling the results to display with a simple line of PHP?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this... also try to understand it.

Keeping with the established coding style:

```
<?php $nlLogo = get_option('nl_logo'); ?>
<?php if (empty($nlLogo)) { ?>
    <h1><a href="<?php echo(get_site_url()); ?>"><?php echo(bloginfo('name')); ?></a></h1>
<?php } else { ?>
    <img src="<?php echo($nlLogo); ?>">
<?php } ?>
```

That should atleast be valid PHP now. I don't know if the functions you are using are correct, but if they are this should work.

Here is a cleaner way to do it...

```
<?php
    $nlLogo = get_option('nl_logo');
    if (empty($nlLogo)) {
        echo('<h1><a href="'.get_site_url().'">'.bloginfo('name').'</a></h1>');            
    } else {
        echo('<img src="'.$nlLogo.'">');
    }
?>
```

Option three because I'm feeling "teachy" using a ternary. Probably a little long for this to be the best choice, but it is another option.

```
<?php
    $nlLogo = get_option('nl_logo');
    echo(empty($nlLogo) ? '<h1><a href="'.get_site_url().'">'.bloginfo('name').'</a></h1>' : '<img src="'.$nlLogo.'">');
?>
```

Note I switched the if / else because I'm using empty and it just feels cleaner to do it this way instead of using !empty()

Comment: why closing php tags when php continues in second line? Not really good way to write if statements. Please don't use braces in this kind of clause.

Comment: I removed ? > < ? php

Comment: since this is within HTML it's actually cleaner to to do it this way IMO. If it were me I'd do it as pure PHP with echos since it's mostly PHP. I just did that to match the style of PHP one liners mixed in to HTML.

Comment: I just added a version that is a little cleaner. Regarding @Hardy's comment about the braces. A lot of people are picky about this, but it's for code readability and for something that's only a few lines braces are A-OK. Anyone could follow the logic in this code without a problem. For longer blocks you can use the alternative syntax like this: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php

Comment: @Lenny +1 for giving the option with ternary.

Comment: Your cleaner version doesn't work for me. Is there a way to get the option from the if statement instead of creating new variables? This will be very useful to know for future projects.

Comment: For the cleaner version there is a chance that some of those functions do not return the value but actually echo them which would be one reason why it wouldn't work.

Comment: You can't use empty() on a function so it won't work directly but you can just check to se if it is an empty string (""). The catch is you need to know what the function get_option is going to return. As long as it returns "" it will work, but often functions will return false instead which does NOT EQUAL "". anyways it's like this: if (get_option('nl_logo') == "") { ...code... }

Comment: If I want to use the if statement to say "if the variable (being what what saved in the input) has information, echo some HTML", how would the line be written?

Comment: if it's a variable you can use !empty($variable) !=NOT... NOT EMPTY... but you're not allowed to do that to a function (get_option is a function) so you have to store it to a variable first like in the example above.

Comment: That's what I thought, however when I tried it, it didn't work.

Comment: empty is anything that is null, false, an empty array, the number zero, or the string "". If you're just looking for null you can use isset or if you know exactly what type of value to expect you can do != "" or != 0.. [this explains empty and isset pretty well](http://itslennysfault.com/php-isset-vs-empty)

Comment: So I would do this? 'if (isset($nlLogo)) {'

Comment: Oops! It's actually  if (!isset($nlLogo)) {

Answer (score 1):

```
<h1><a href="'get_site_url()' ?>"><?php bloginfo('name'); ?></a></h1>
```

Should be

```
<h1><a href="<?php echo get_site_url() ?>"><?php echo bloginfo('name'); ?></a></h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are testing for string "nl_logo" to be true. That returns always true.

try changing your code like this:

```
<?php

   $nl_logo = get_option('nl_logo');

   if (!empty($nl_logo)): 
?>
    <img src="<?php echo $nl_logo; ?>">

<?php else: ?>

<h1><a href="<?php echo get_site_url() ?>"><?php bloginfo('name'); ?></a></h1>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Excellent spotting.. I didn't see that :)

Answer (score 0):

You could try the [`empty`](http://php.net/empty) method to test if a string is empty. In context:

```
if(!empty($nl_logo)) {
    // stuff
} else {
    // other stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This does not make sense:

```
if ("nl_logo")
```

You're basically saying if the string exists then proceed, which it does, of course.

It makes more sense to take the input string:

```
$input = $_POST["postedInput"];
```

As an example, doesn't really matter as long as you know how you got the value into `$input`.

Now, you can use the [ternary operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation) to determine whether you want to use the user's input or if you want to use the default title:

```
$img = $input == "" ? bloginfo($input) : get_option($input);
```

Depending on what your functions do.. if get_options returns a string then this will work.

Anyway, don't mis PHP and HTML, it will make things complicated and you'll be locked into bad design.

Note:

Make sure to check if the input is actually received, using `isset`.

Answer (score -1):

Don't close the php tags.

Whatever html you need to write, just write it as echo statements within one big php block.

This should fix your problem